# How to re-order list item on resize, only once if condition is met

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check the width of my screen on resize and load.  If my window is less then 800px width, i want to make my last li item first.

If the window is 800 or greater I want to make sure the last li remain last.

.content-search-click is on a an anchor within the li, that I am moving around.  I pretty much want it to be first on smaller screens, and last on larger screens.

Here is what I am working with...

```
function msearch() {



$(window).on("resize", function () {

var mtargetmenu = $('#menu ul');
var mtargetfirst = $('#menu li:first');
var mtargetlast = $('#menu li:last');
var mtarget = $('.content-search-click'); 

            var mwin =  $(window).width();
            if (mwin < 800) {
       mtargetmenu.prepend(mtargetlast); //i want this to only occur once if it didnt do so already...
            } else {
             mtargetfirst.appendTo(mtargetmenu); //i want this to only occur once if it didn't so do already...
            }       
}).resize();
}
msearch();
```

thanks for any advice

**update - Because my code may appear confusing...I want to do something like this...**

```
function msearch() {


var mtargetmenu = $('#menu ul');
var mtargetfirst = $('#menu li:first');
var mtargetlast = $('#menu li:last');
var mtarget = $('.content-search-click'); 


$(window).one( "resize", function() {
        var mwin =  $(window).width();
            if (mwin < 800) {
            console.log('window is smaller than 800');
       mtargetmenu.prepend(mtargetlast);
            } else {
            console.log('window is larger than 800');
             mtargetfirst.find(mtarget).appendTo(mtargetmenu);
            }
    }).resize();

}


msearch();
```

Does that help see what I am trying to do?  complete the action once, but always check where the user is at on drag....

Comment: So why not using the window onload event instead of resize and triggering it anyway?!

Comment: `$(window).on('load', msearch);` or `window.onload = msearch;`  Without the resize handler inside msearch function

Comment: i want to check if the user drags their screen less then 800px, the last li item with .content-search-click, should move to become the first li

Comment: @blackhawk are the `li` elements static or dynamic ? (*are they created on the fly*)

Comment: I'm loading the li items in via Ajax onto the page

Comment: resize is causing my li item to added again, and again and again, everytime I drag.  I only want to add it once to the front, if the sceen is less than 800px.  but the wierd thing is that if i resize it larger than 800px, then less then 800px, the code stops working

Comment: sorry for the confusion - I'm trying to learn this process too, which is why it may appear confusing...perhaps i am over-engineering this process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if i understand correctly you only want to move the last item. Keep it last while the browser is more than 800 or make it first if it is smaller.

If so

```
var lastValue  = 800; // as breakpoint
var mtargetmenu = $('#menu ul');
var mtargetlast = mtargetmenu.children().last();

$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var mwin = $(window).width();

    // check if we fell below 800 from a bigger screen
    if (lastValue > mwin && mwin < 800){
        mtargetmenu.prepend(mtargetlast );
    }
    // check if we went over or equal to 800 from a smaller screen
    if (lastValue < mwin && mwin >= 800){
        mtargetmenu.append(mtargetlast );
    }

    lastValue = mwin;
}).resize();
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/xvk0fbgn/1

---

you will need to re-assign the `mtargetlast` variable if you reload the data with ajax.

Comment: super close!  I only want to move the last item, to the first position, if the screen is less then 800px width.  if the screen is loaded or resize to 800 or larger, keep the last item as the last item.  But if the user drags their screen smaller again, then make sure the last item is first.

Comment: @blackhawk yes, i had it backwards. Have a look at it now

Comment: I'm pretty much moving that **<li><a class="content-search-click"></a></li>** around